# How to represent the current business situation using process flow or modelling?

Tags: process, process-improvement, business-case, process-engineering, business-process-mapping

I am working on a small case study of the restaurant who is suffering a loss in business of nearly about 70-80% due to COVID-19 situation so the business owner would like to revamp his whole business model to increase his sales and revenues.

I want to create AS-IS process for my team to represent the current state of business but I dont have much idea regarding how and whats the best way to create AS-IS process for current business.

As of now, I have the presentation document from the client where I have all the pain points basically the problem and expectations of the client.

Can someone please guide me of what and how to create the AS-IS process flow for current business ?

Comment: You've already asked this exact question before. While your final sentence makes this slightly less discussion-oriented, it's not really any more on topic than the original. Process mapping and modeling are at best tangential to project management; from a PM perspective, the only reasonable answer is to staff your project with team members with experience in business process modeling/re-engineering.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs This question is different from the one I have asked before as here I am asking about representing the current business process using the AS-Is process and whats the best way of representing it. I dont know why you have marked it as duplicate

Comment: Even if I’m incorrect about it being a duplicate, it still appears to be off topic. Just because something is part of a project doesn’t mean the question is inherently *about* project management.